# Expose Parent's DataContext to children through Resource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I have a situation where the parent DataContext is different from the child DataContext, and I would like to access the parent DataContext from a binding in the child.  This can be done using a verbose RelativeSource like so:

```
 <Button Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}, Path=DataContext.Bar}"/>
```

I would like to find a way to reference the parent's DataContext in a much more concise way.  Is there a way, for example, the parent could expose a reference to it's DataContext (or any of it's properties for that matter) through a Resource defined in the parent?  Ideally, the child's binding would then look something like the following (forgive me for using StaticResource as an example).

```
 <Button Path=Bar, Content="{StaticResource parentDataContextReference}"/>
```

Ideally, avoiding code-behind, but open to that solution. A contrived example:

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="BindingTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BindingTest"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <x:ArrayExtension x:Key="children" Type="{x:Type local:ChildViewModel}">
        <local:ChildViewModel Name="Child 1"/>
        <local:ChildViewModel Name="Child 2"/>
    </x:ArrayExtension>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="{Binding Foo}" Height="20" Width="60"></Button>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{StaticResource children}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:ChildView/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
namespace BindingTest
{
    public class MainViewModel
    {
        public string Foo { get; set; }
        public string Bar { get; set; }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Foo = "Foo";
            Bar = "Bar";
        }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new MainViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

ChildView.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="BindingTest.ChildView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BindingTest"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Content="{Binding Name}"/>
        <Button Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}, Path=DataContext.Bar}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

ChildView.xaml.cs

```
namespace BindingTest
{
    public class ChildViewModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ChildViewModel()
        {
            Name = "Undefined";
        }
    }

    public partial class ChildView : UserControl
    {
        public ChildView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why dont you like the relativesource stuff?

Comment: How about `<Button Content="{Binding Bar.SomeBarProperty}"/>`? Nothing else needed.

Comment: @blindmeis - it's fine for one off situations, but I am hoping for a much more concise/readable/less error prone way of referencing something in the parent's DataContext.  If there was some sort of alias I could setup it would be half the characters and a much simpler syntax.

Comment: @Clemens - sorry, I don't understand the suggestion. Bar is not a property that the ChildView.DataContext contains.  Do you mean what if the ChildViewModel had a reference to the MainViewModel?

Comment: In your RelativeSource example you are binding the Button's Content to a `Bar` property in the DataContext of the MainWindow. You don't need to do that, as the DataContext is inherited to child elements of MainWindow. The binding could be written as `Content="{Binding Bar}"`.

Comment: @Clemens - the child has it's own DataContext per the <ListView> templating. That overrides the one that otherwise would be inherited from the parent.

Comment: Sorry, I've missed the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

to long for a comment... i use RelativeSource Binding too. but i use it with "Marker Interfaces". this means simply empty interfaces which i'm putting on the Views/UserControls.

```
 public interface IMainWindowMarker {}


 public Window MainWindow : IMainWindowMarker {}
```

the binding the looks much the same to yours but its more readable to me.

```
<Button Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:IMainWindowMarker}}, Path=DataContext.Bar}"/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that looks basically the same for my purposes.  My objective is to reduce the binding reference to one token, probably a Resource exposed by the parent. `<Button Path=Bar, Content="{StaticResource parentDataContextReference}"/>

Comment: but if you do something like this you have to look at two spots to check whats going on.